# Posting image with caption with Facebook IOS SDK 3.1 and Graph API

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm new to facebook SDK.
Last time I used facebook IOS SDK 3.0 and posting image through graph API. It is working but now it's not. I upgraded to 3.1 but still, it always return HTTP ERROR 200. Is there anyone can help me?

this is the code

```
- (void) facebookPostPhoto:(UIImage *)photo withMessage:(NSString *)msg withOkAction:(SEL)okAction andNGAction:(SEL)ngAction withTarget:(id)target {
ok = okAction;
ng = ngAction;
curView = target;
NSMutableDictionary *params;
params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 90), @"source",
          msg, @"message",             
          nil];

if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:FacebookPermission_3] == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"permission not found");
    // No permissions found in session, ask for it
    [FBSession.activeSession reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:FacebookPermission_1, FacebookPermission_3, nil] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error)
     {
         // If permissions granted, publish the story
         if (!error) [self initPostFacebookWithParams:params];
     }];
} else {
    [self initPostFacebookWithParams:params];
} } 

- (void)initPostFacebookWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params {

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR : %@", error.localizedDescription);
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Facebook Post Success..");
        if (ok && curView) {
            [curView performSelector:ok];
        }


    } else {
        NSLog(@"Facebook Post Failed..");
        if (ng && curView) {
            [curView performSelector:ng withObject:error];
        }

    }

}]; }
```

I appreciate your fast response and help! Thank You!!

Comment: are u sure you have the permission to publish? when calling [self initPostFacebookWithParams:params]; the error code you are mentioning is a permission error code

Comment: yes. [FBSession.activeSession reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:...

I used that before. and I use both publish_actions and publish_stream

Comment: do you see your log NSLog(@"permission not found");?

Comment: yes. sometime i see it. and when it was done, HTTP error 200 still exists

Comment: I am not so sure about your FacebookPermission_1, FacebookPermission_3 i am just passing publish_actions - could you give it a try with this?

Comment: nope.. it doesn't work. very strange. 
It goes to facebook app because of no permission, and then bounce back. and error 200 :(

Comment: FacebookPermission_1 or publish_actions is just a string associated to the publish permissions so in fact you can use what ever you want but why are you mixing two permissions then?

Comment: fixed it myself. I think it's either facebook upload's server is down or there is a new policy about image size. When I down sized the image to 320x320 it returns no error, sometimes error too by the way. Thank you for your response tiguero! Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think it's either facebook upload's server is down or there is a new policy about image size. When I down sized the image to 320x320 it returns no error, sometimes error too by the way.

So for those who see this question, try to resize your image to smaller size.